# Flask SQLAlchemy query.all() using SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am following this tutorial [microblog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) to implement a web app.
I'm stuck in the "play time" paragraph.
When I run this command in the python console `users = User.query.all()`

My editor Pycharm returns this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 12404 and this is thread id 7880.
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.password_hash AS user_password_hash 
FROM user]
[parameters: [immutabledict({})]]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Just reload IDE. It has to do with threads, but reloading solves the problem.
I understand that it's already late, but maybe it will help someone.